# Why isn't my expression auto-updating in Angular upon page load?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having trouble figuring out how to make one of my expressions auto-update when the page first loads in Angular. I am using a service to grab a JSON object, and assigning it to `$scope.stocks`. I am using `$watch` to dynamically update `$scope.thisStock` any time a date slider value updates -- that works just fine. However, when the page initially loads, `$scope.thisStock` is undefined. Additionally, I am getting an annoying error message in the console:

[image: $scope.stocks is undefined error message]

What is the best, most elegant way for me to resolve these issues? How can I keep my controller from attempting to read `$scope.stocks` before the asynchronous call has resolved, and how can I best force Angular to load `$scope.thisStock` as soon as possible, without me having to first move the date slider?

Here is my controller:

```
sim.controller("StocksCtrl", ['$scope', 'StockService', 'DateService',
  function($scope, StockService, DateService) {

    $scope.init = function() {
      $scope.getStocks();
    };

    $scope.getStocks = function() {
      StockService.all().then(function(stocks){
        $scope.stocks = stocks;
      });
    };

    $scope.$watch(function() {return DateService.getCurrentDate()}, function(newValue) {
      $scope.currentDate = newValue;
      $scope.reformatCurrentDate();
    });

    $scope.reformatCurrentDate = function() {
      var arr = $scope.currentDate.split("/");
      if (arr[1].length === 1) {
        arr[1] = "0" + arr[1];
      }
      $scope.reformattedCurrentDate = arr[2] + "-" + arr[0] + "-" + arr[1];
    };

    $scope.$watch('reformattedCurrentDate', function() {
      $scope.thisStock = $scope.stocks[$scope.reformattedCurrentDate]["price"];
    });

}]);
```

And here is the relevant section of the HTML index:

```
{{thisStock | currency}}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$watch` function runs when the change detection happens for `reformattedCurrentDate` variable. But watch function gets called before `$scope.stocks` get values from an asynchronous call. so simply put an if condition to check the `$scope.stocks` is not null.

```
$scope.$watch('reformattedCurrentDate', function() {
     if($scope.stocks) {
         $scope.thisStock = $scope.stocks[$scope.reformattedCurrentDate]["price"];
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first load, Angular will fire the `$watch` event once.
Your app defines the variable `$scope.stocks` after an async request but your watch function will fire before this and you'll get undefined on `$scope.stocks[$scope.reformattedCurrentDate]["price"]` because `$scope.stocks` is not yet an array.

You should be checking if `$scope.stocks` is not an empty array with something like `$scope.stocks != null && $scope.stocks.length > 0` inside your watch function before you're not sure if this has the value you need. Also consider the case that your backend response fails and the response might not contain your array.

Optionally you can detect this first watch run comparing the old value and the new value as they will be equal.

Regarding to setting the initial value of `$scope.thisStock` I would suggest setting it alongside `$scope.stocks` inside your request response as this is the earliest possible place to access your data and you can be sure the request is successful:

```
    $scope.getStocks = function() {
      StockService.all().then(function(stocks){
        $scope.stocks = stocks;
        $scope.thisStocks = <FIRST_AVAILABLE_DATE>
      });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is the only place where

```
$scope.reformattedCurrentDate = arr[2] + "-" + arr[0] + "-" + arr[1];
```

$scope.reformattedCurrentDate changes, then you dont need watch anyway right, unnecessary increase in number of function calls.

```
$scope.reformattedCurrentDate = arr[2] + "-" + arr[0] + "-" + arr[1];
$scope.thisStock = $scope.stocks[$scope.reformattedCurrentDate]["price"];
```

This will do, and you can remove watch. Then as everyone is saying you need to initialise $scope.thisStock and check for the usage $scope.stock or initialise that too with some default value at start of the controller.